# Eclipse set build automatically option In eclipse off by default

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, salesforce

Is any way to do that? 
I found the preference definition : 
org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.PREF_AUTO_BUILDING

but I don't know where to update it.

[this link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/109624/) explain how to do that but i can't find the  plugin_customization.ini  file of the force.com plugin

Answer (score 0):

This is only one `plugin_customization.ini` file and that is in the product plugin for your Eclipse installation. This file is in the Eclipse installation directory **not** the workspace.

For my installation the product plugin is `org.eclipse.sdk` but depending on which build of Eclipse you installed yours may be different.